# Change a toggle in VueJS to two buttons to show and hide elements

Tags: vue.js

I have a button that toggles different parts of my app.

I would like to make these 2 buttons instead to show and hide various parts of my app.

How can I achieve this?

```
<button v-on:click="isViewable = !isViewable">Togggggle</button>         
<span v-if="isViewable">
<input
  class="form-control form-control-lg d-none d-md-block"
  type="text"                  
  v-model="search_input"                  
  />
</span>
<span v-if="!isViewable">
<input
  class="form-control form-control-lg d-none d-md-block"
  type="text"                   
  v-model="search_input_2"                  
  /> 
</span>
```

```
data: function () {
  return {
    isViewable: true,
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain why do you want to create two buttons? If there would be more than 2 parts in your app, would you create more than two buttons to toggle those?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just create a seperate property for each part of your app? (If you have a lot of components, it might make sense to combine those into an array)

I imagined something like this:

```
<template>
  <button @click="showPart1 = !showPart1">Toggle Part 1</button>
  <button @click="showPart2 = !showPart2">Toggle Part 2</button>

  <span v-if="showPart1">
    <h1>Part 1</h1>
  </span>
  <span v-if="showPart2">
    <h1>Part 2</h1>
  </span>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data: function () {
    return {
      showPart1: true,
      showPart2: false,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you will want to add some logic to those toggles is better to do like this and add some additional logic in methods. In the button is trigger only but logic is placed in methods. It's is more readable.

```
<template>
  <button @click="showPart1">Toggle Part 1</button>
  <button @click="showPart2">Toggle Part 2</button>

  <span v-if="showPart1">
    <h1>Part 1</h1>
  </span>
  <span v-if="showPart2">
    <h1>Part 2</h1>
  </span>
</template>

export default {
    setup() {
        const showPart1 = false;
        const showPart2 = false;


        return {
            showPart1,
            showPart2,
        }
    },
    methods: {
    showPart1() {
    //additional logic for showPart1
    console.log(showPart1);
    },
    showPart2() {
    //additional logic for showPart1
    console.log(showPart1);
    },
    data() {
        return {
            showPart1: false,
            showPart2: false,
        }
    }
}
</script>
```